# Method that operates in a specific object (textBox)

Tags: c#

I wanna create a method that is called using:

```
 methodname(textBoxX);
```

What i want it to do is change a property of the textBoxX like

```
  private void methodname(Object textbox)
 {
  tryparse (textbox.Text, out somevariable);
  textbox.Text = something;

 }
```

Comment: Why not `TextBox textbox` instead of `Object textbox`?

Comment: Are you familiar with C#?

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to create a method with a TextBox as the parameter? Of course...

Comment: @gustavodidomenico barely, why do you ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...this question raises plenty of others, but if you're wanting to check if an `object` passed into a method is a `TextBox`, and then to set the `Text` property of that, you'd need:

```
private void ChangeText(object target)
{
    var tBox = target as TextBox;

    if (tBox != null)
        tBox.Text = "new value";  
}
```

**EDIT**

This is now straying into the area where I'd want to ask why you need this, as what I'm going to suggest may well not be the best answer to the problem, but here we go. If you want to know if an object has a `Text` property, and to set that value accordingly, you can use this.

On my *.aspx page, I have:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="CheckBox1" />
<asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="RadioButton1" />
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel1"></asp:Panel>
```

My `Page_Load` event looks like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChangeText(TextBox1);
    ChangeText(RadioButton1);
    ChangeText(CheckBox1);
    ChangeText(Panel1);
}
```

And the implementation of `ChangeText()` is as follows:

```
private void ChangeText(object target)
{
    var textProperty = target.GetType().GetProperty("Text");

    if (textProperty != null)
    {
        try
        {
            target.GetType().GetProperty("Text").SetValue(target, "New Value", null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is ArgumentException
                || ex is MethodAccessException
                || ex is TargetInvocationException)
            {
                // Unable to set the property for whatever reason
                return;
            }

            // All other exceptions -- something unexpected happened.
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

The first three elements have their `Text` properties amended; the `Panel` does not, as there's no `Text` property on there.

Comment: but i could use a check box or radio button as any other target, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. Although, I would do what Dmitry is saying above and use `TextBox txtBx1` as your parameter. By doing so you pass in a TextBox object and can then access all the TextBox methods and properties ie `txtBx1.Text="some text"`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, but you don't need to make the parameter an Object, just make it a TextBox.